# Using WebStorm's debugger with TypeScript and Ava

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, webstorm, ava

Has anyone figured out setting breakpoints in WebStorm/IntelliJ without generating sourcemaps when running tests via Ava?

Comment: you can't debug typescript without sourcemaps - there is no way to map original code to the one that is actually executed if sourcemaps are not generated

Comment: Point. I found that Ava does have plans to support `ts-node/register` in `v1.0`